# Samples for RESTful web services for WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am new to RESTful web services in WCF, but not new to WCF. I want to develop some simple RESTful web services in WCF which manually be accessed from a browser. Any good samples or documents to recommend? I am using C#.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aaron Skonnard of PluralSight has a bunch of great little screencasts on Channel9 and is probably the best intro I've seen - you'll probably do well to have some WCF experience first - those coming from the world of SOAP will pick it up easier.

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Screencast-Building-RESTful-Services-with-WCF/

Also, stick this in Bing

restful site:msdn.com

**UPDATE**

This answer still gets votes, so I thought it would be good to update it with recent changes. Basically, the WCF team have joined forces with the ASP.NET MVC community to bring REST to the Microsoft stack via ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API, so I guess the WCF REST stuff will not be developed from 2012 on.

http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20Web%20API%20is%20now%20ASP.NET%20Web%20API

Comment: Thanks, it is video training. I prefer to have some documents and copyable code, any suggestions?

Comment: Sure, there's a whole starter kit and part of MSDN for RESTful services. Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529.aspx and good luck!

Comment: Woo! Too many stuff in the portal, any recommendations where to read begin with? I need some step-by-step simple samples to write restful web services.

Comment: To be honest, download the starter kit as it has samples and new templates for VS.

Like anything, you can't save time learning, only reorder what you spend time doing.

Watch the first getting started with the SDK screencast and use a project template to kick things off.

I've not actually created anything but I watched and read alot about the REST kit in order to prepare to convert my beta SOAP services.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a short blog [post](http://toranbillups.com/blog/archive/2009/07/07/Getting-familiar-with-REST-and-WCF/) showing how to build REST services using WCF (sample code included).  Keep in mind this example does not use the REST Toolkit released by Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

You can also refer an example to create and get help of very basic restful service from [here](http://sandeepkumar1234.blogspot.com/2013/04/simple-steps-to-prepare-restful-serviec.html)

Answer (score 0):

Some one wrote a short blog post showing how to build REST services using WCF (sample code included).

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201901/CREATE-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Using-POST-Step-By

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! When you post an answer with an external link, it's useful to try and include some of the major points in your post. This way, in case the link goes dead later, people can still read your answer to get what they need.